# Connecting a Stove Top

Tags: electrical

I have a cook top, it has a black and red wire along with ground completely exposed.  I need to connect it to a black, red and white along with ground...

I know the red and black wires connect, what do I do with the white one, and how do I connect the ground from the stove top to the main wires of the house?

Please advise.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: OK, We're going to need a few pictures of the main wires from your house, the wires from the cook top  and the name plate of your cook top. Do you know the size of the breaker that feeds the cook top.

Comment: It's hard to know for sure with the minimal information you have provided but many cooktops take only RED (HOT) and BLACK (HOT) and GROUND, no need for the WHITE (NEUTRAL) wire.  Check the installation manual for the unit to be sure.

Comment: Can you post the make and model of your cooktop, and a photo of the inside of the box please?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, we'll need more info before we have any chance of helping you. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Answer (score 1):

### Cap off the neutral wire

Despite being neutral, it can have lethal or fire-starting currents on it.  (not least if your utility's drop wire has a problem). That's why neutral wires have insulation.

Your situation is not uncommon; *range tops* have no need for the neutral wire.   Generally ovens and ranges are entirely 240V beasts.  The only reason they ever wanted neutral is to have 120V available, to allow you to use a cheap, common incandescent light for the oven light, and sometimes for a 120V clock or electronics, and sometimes for a convenience receptacle on the oven.  (old incandescents inside a 500 degree oven are as happy as Br'er Rabbit in the briar patch).  Obviously, cooktops don't have oven lights, electronics have evolved to where they work fine on 240V, and UL won't let them fit convenience receptacles anymore.